# How to get the number of enabled and non expired accounts members of an AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to get the number of accounts that are enabled and non expired of an AD group. I'm able to get the enabled accounts but I'm having problems with those that are expired.

I've been reading about how to do that and I found many solutions that are basically the same:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DisName |get-aduser|Where{$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.AccountExpires -ne 0}
```

That's not working. I've checked for the value of the Property AccountExpires of an expired account and is not equal to 0. I've also compared this value among different Expiration Dates such as: Expired, expiring today, expiring tomorrow and Never Expires, to try to find something relevant among the values, but I didn't find anything.

This is my code:

```
$DisName = 'CN=demo1group,OU=groups,OU=demo1,OU=res10000,OU=Customer,DC=cloud,DC=local'
$lic = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DisName |get-aduser|Where{$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.AccountExpires -ne 0}).count
```

I've tried to force to expire an account but I always get the same value for $lic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccountExpires value is always a FileTime value of 9223372036854775807 UNLESS you modify a user to expire at which point the AccountExpires value changes to 0 for never expire (this changed to 0 for all AD users in my lab)

I manually set an expired date of 9th January 2019 on my lab and get:

```
AccountExpirationDate                : 10/01/2019 00:00:00
accountExpires                       : 131915520000000000
```

so you may be better off setting a variable $currentdate = Get-Date and then doing a comparison operator against the AccountExpirationDate parameter instead?

Here's some sample code that validates it in my lab:

```
$currrentdate = (Get-Date).ToFileTime()
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> | get-aduser -Properties * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -ne $null -and $_.AccountExpires -lt $currrentdate} | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName,AccountExpirationDate,AccountExpires
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DisName | Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled,AccountExpires | Where { $_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.AccountExpires -ne 0 }
```

`Get-ADUser` only returns a limited set of properties by default, but you can use `-Properties` to return a specific list of additional properties, or use `-Properties *` to return all properties.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but I still have the problem. It's not working because the value of the property AccountExpires of an expired account is not equal to 0.

Comment: It would be worth checking the pipeline piece by piece. First run `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DisName` and see if you get the group members back that you expect. Then run `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DisName | Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled,AccountExpires` and see if you get the users back that you expect.

Comment: I've checked it. In fact, the code works well if I only look for enabled user accounts. The problem comes when I try to get the expired accounts.